# Event isn't firing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have appended the following HTML to a Div called `videoList` but when I click the link it isn't firing the ajax call but it's going to the url defined in `href`. I have tried javascript void in href but still it's not firing the ajax on click. No error is present in console!

```
 var newHtml = '<div class="group-seemore">';
                        newHtml +=    '<a class="ajax-cate-mobile" data-slug="' + res.category.slug + '" data-start="5" href="/blog/category/'+ res.category.slug +'" title="">';
                        newHtml +=    'See more';
                        newHtml +=    '</a>';
                        newHtml +=    '</div>';
                        $('#videoList').append(newHtml);
```

Ajax:

```
$('.ajax-cate-mobile').click(function(e){
            console.log('hi');
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var start = $this.parents('.blog-groups').find('.ajax-cate-mobile').data('start');
            params.start = start;
            var newStart = start + 10;
            $this.parents('.blog-groups').find('.ajax-cate-mobile').data('start', newStart);

            $(this).style="border-bottom:1px solid #197B81";
            var _loader = '<div class="ajax-loader"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>';
            //$('#videoList').empty().html(_loader);
            var cate_slug = $(this).attr('data-slug');
            params.cate_slug = cate_slug;
            ajaxLoadVideoInMobile(params, $this);
            $('.submenu').fadeOut();
            $('.ajax-loader').fadeOut();
        });
```

Comment: Is your first code run BEFORE your second code?

Comment: timing is irrelevant if you bind the event using `on` @HerrSerker

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events - read the bit about delegated event handlers

Comment: @Liam That's true, but it wasn't clear that this was the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the event with the help of a parent which already exists:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajax-cate-mobile", function() {
    // Your code 
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked